# Using Foreach method to perform an OR or AND Operation

Tags: c#

I have the following piece of code which uses the foreach iterator.

```
foreach (var item in daysOfWeeksList)
            {
                daysOper |= item;
            }
```

daysOfWeeksList is a list. I want to OR each item in the list and process the result?

This daysOfWeeksList is a

```
List<int> daysOfWeeksList
```

Say I wan to do something like this. The dosomething I want to do is the OR operation.

```
list.ForEach( item =>
{
    item.DoSomething();
} );
```

How would you go about this using an foreach method available as part of the List collection? I got plenty of examples for this for 2 operands but not for a single operand.

Comment: Define what you mean _foreach_ extension. `Linq` (it's not `foreach` extension, btw)?

Comment: I, for one, do not know what you mean.

Comment: Updated the question based on the comments.

Comment: @ckv `ForEach` is not extension method. It lives in class `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

Comment: @PLB: Yes, i have updated my question based on your comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `daysOper` starts as 0, I wouldn't use `ForEach` at all - I'd use `Aggregate` from LINQ:

```
var daysOper = daysOfWeekList.Aggregate((current, next) => current | next);
```

In other words, keep a running "current" value, and keep OR-ing it with the next value each time. (The result of one iteration will be used as the "current" value for the next iteration.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, you want to use the [Aggregate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx) for stuff like this where the standard aggragetors, like [Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) don't fit.

*(Edit: I assumed that the OP was doing the OR operation over a List. So I edited the below paragraph)*
However, if DaysOfWeekList is a List, then have the opportunity to optimize performance by stopping at the first instance of "true". The [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) method does this.

```
var result = daysOfWeekList.Any(daysOpr=>daysOpr);
```

Comment: I think you're assuming `daysOfWeeksList` is a `List<bool>`. I suspect it's actually a `List<DayOfWeek>` or something similar.

Comment: Well the List is a List<int>. In otherwords it is a list of integer values.

Comment: Right, then you'd want to go with the Aggregate method. You should also check the different overloads of it and be able to calculate Sum, Mean, Max and Product using it.